# How to extend flexbox pseudo-element lines to full width of the container?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a layout with a section of text and two links, where I want lines to extend from the end of each link to the end of the container. I can achieve this using position: absolute; and setting a fixed width on the pseudo-elements, but I'm looking for a way to do this with Flexbox so that the lines are dynamically sized based on the parent container's width.

Here's my current attempt at using flexbox for this.

HTML structure:

```
<div class="hero-text">
        <h1><a href=#>CURRENT EXHIBITIONS</a></h1>
        <div class="hero-text-bottom">
            <div class="title">
                <h2><a href=#>SPECIAL EVENTS</a></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="additional-links">
                <div class="link-with-line">
                    <a href="#" class="hero-small-link">CONTACT</a>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="link-with-line">
                    <a href="#" class="hero-small-link-two">CONTRIBUTE TO THE MUSEUM</a>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And CSS:

```
.hero-text {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    margin-left: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    font-family: var(--font-primary);
    color: white;
    font-size: 3rem;
}

.hero-text-bottom {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; 
}

.additional-links {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    gap: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    width: 50%;
}

.title {
    width: 75%;
}

.link-with-line {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%; 
}

.line {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    top: 50%; 
    width: 100%; 
    border-top: 1px solid white; 
    transform: translateY(-50%); 
}

.hero-small-link, .hero-small-link-two {
    z-index: 1; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

It works, but i have to use nowrap on the text, and i also think my html is definitely overcomplicating it.

Any help with how to do this properly?

I tried using position absolute, which works, but i want to use flexbox for a more clean look.

When using flexbox i expected it to be nothing more than adding an inline-line element to the right side of each text element, and set it to flex grow or width 100%, but it does not work.

Expected result: i.stack.imgur.com/4JnMg.png
What i get: i.stack.imgur.com/Ae6y5.png

Answer (score 0):

Use a pseudo-element and simplify your HTML. No need for additional divs etc.

```css
.additional-links {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  gap: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: .5em;
}

.hero-small-link {
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  color: black;
}

.hero-small-link:after {
  content: "";
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: .5em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid currentColor
}
```

```html
<div class="additional-links">
  <a href="#" class="hero-small-link">CONTACT</a>
  <a href="#" class="hero-small-link">CONTRIBUTE TO THE MUSEUM</a>
</div>
```